# SQL to Merge Multiple Child Records into a single row with new columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called OrderDetail. I also have a child table called PriceCategories.

Each OrderDetail can have multiple PriceCategories (eg A = $1, B = 2$, C = 3$, etc...)

I want to somehow allow a single resulting record when I am doing a SQL Query on OrderDetail joined to PriceCategories, but returning each record in PriceCategories as columns in a single row.

For example using a normal Join I would end up with.

```
OrderID | PriceCat | Amount 
1            A          1
1            B          2
1            C          3
```

What I want to end up with is something like;

```
OrderId | CatAAmount | CatBAmount | CatCAmount
1           1             2           3
```

Is there anyway within a SQL statement that can achieve this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a case statement -

```
SELECT order_id,
   CASE
     WHEN pricecat = 'A' THEN
      amount
   END AS cataamount,
   CASE
     WHEN pricecat = 'B' THEN
      amount
   END AS catbamount,
   CASE
     WHEN pricecat = 'C' THEN
      amount
   END AS catcamount
FROM table
```

Comment: Thanks. This is awesome, but what if I do not know how many Price Cats there are? Could be 1 to n.

Comment: You need to `GROUP BY`, to get one row per id.

Comment: Also, those are case _expressions_, not statements.

Comment: I don't know - maybe try researching how to PIVOT in SQL. https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-sql-sql-server-pivot-tables/

Answer (score 1):

Using pivot.

```
SELECT OrderID, [A] CatAAmount,[B] CatBAmount, [C] CatCAmount  
FROM   
(SELECT OrderID, PriceCat, Amount    
FROM test) p  
PIVOT  
(  
max (Amount)  
FOR PriceCat IN  
( [A],[B],[C])  
) AS pvt;
```

If you have more categories you can simply add them in the 'FOR' and 'SELECT' clause.
Please refer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e19ac/13/0